# Java - While loop (Help me to understand the flow)

Tags: java, while-loop

When i run this code, i get UNREACHABLE STATEMENT error. But if i change false to true(in 2nd while) then the output comes as: "1 0" and execution continues .
What happens inside???

```
int m=2;
while (m >0)
{
 m =m -1;
 System.out.println(m);
} while (false);
```

Output:" error: unreachable statement "

But if,

```
int m=2;
while (m >0)
{
 m =m -1;
 System.out.println(m);
} while (true);
```

Output: "1 0            "

Thanks in advance...

Comment: do you seriously indent block with just one space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets format your code a little:

```
int m = 2;
while (m > 0) {
    m = m - 1;
    System.out.println(m);
}
while (false)
    ;
```

As you see you have two loops here, first regarding `while (m > 0)` and second `while (false)`. Lets focus on second loop

```
while (false)
    ;
```

There are two mistakes here

1. this loop will never iterate because its condition is always *false* so potential code which should be executed will never be reached (it is unreachable statement).
2. even if condition in this loop could be evaluated to *true*, it has no instruction to execute (instruction before semicolon is empty) so this loop is equivalent of

   ```
   while (false){
       //nothing 
   }
   ```

Now reason why you see error about unreachable statements is because according to [Java Language Specification 14.21](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21)

> It is a compile-time error if a statement cannot be executed because it is unreachable.

---

Now if you change condition in this loop to `while (true)` problem of unreachable statements inside this loop will disappear, but two bad things will happen

1. you will end up creating infinite loop which will do nothing (except taking processor time)

   ```
   while (true){
       //will do nothing forever
   }
   ```
2. because of this infinite loop instructions placed after it will be unreachable so something like

   ```
   while (true){
       //will do nothing forever
   }
   System.out.println("foo");//unreachable
   ```

   will cause same error as before.

Answer (score 5):

Both your examples are weird, and I the issue is that...

```
while (m >0)
{
 m =m -1;
 System.out.println(m);
} while (false);
```

...actually means

```
while (m >0)
{
 m =m -1;
 System.out.println(m);
}

// another while statement
while (false)
    ; //  loop's body - empty statement
```

Therefore, the body of the second `while` statement is never reached (the semicolon = empty statement).

If you put `true` there, you've made an infinite loop - not sure if that's your aim tho.

I believe you confused the `do {...} while(...);` syntax with `while(...) {...}` and created some bizzare hybrid of the two.

Comment: As I said, the second while loop has empty statement as a body. Because it's condition is "false", this statement is never executed. Therefore it's unreachable and you get the error. Now can you accept the answer, please?

Comment: @VimalKumar Don't you think it's *really unfair* to accept THE OTHER answer, which was posted much later and got just one upvote?

Comment: Not that it bothers me, but accepting correct answer is personal choice of OP, it doesn't matter when answer was posted or how many votes it has.